# What is the point of coercions like Int(Cool)?

Tags: raku

[The Perl 6 Web site on functions says](http://doc.perl6.org/language/functions#Coercion_Types)

> Coercion types can help you to have a specific type inside a routine, but accept wider input. When the routine is called, the argument is automatically converted to the narrower type.
>
> ```
> sub double(Int(Cool) $x) {
>     2 * $x
> }
>
> say double '21';    # 42
> say double Any;     # Type check failed in binding $x; expected 'Cool' but got 'Any'
> ```
>
> Here the Int is the target type to which the argument will be coerced, and Cool is the type that the routine accepts as input.

But what is the point for the sub? Isn't `$x` just an `Int`? Why would you restrict the caller to implement `Cool` for the argument?

I'm doubly confused by the example because `Int` already `is Cool`. So I did an example where the types don't share a hierarchy:

```
class Foo { method foomethod { say 'foomethod' } }
class Bar {}

class Quux is Foo {
# class Quux { # compile error
  method Bar { Bar.new }
}

sub foo(Bar(Foo) $c) {
  say $c.WHAT;    # (Bar)
  # $c.foomethod  # fails if uncommented: Method 'foomethod' not found for invocant of class 'Bar'
}

foo(Quux.new)
```

Here the invocant of `foo` is restricted to provide a `Foo` that can be converted to a `Bar` but `foo` cannot even call a method of `Foo` on `$c` because its type *is* `Bar`. So why would `foo` care that the to-be-coerced type is a `Foo` in the first place?

Could someone shed some light on this? Links to appropriate documentation and parts of the spec are appreciated as well. I couldn't find anything useful there.

Comment: you don't restrict  the caller to *also* implement `Cool`, you restrict it to *only* implement `Cool` and to provide a coercion method; `double '21'` passes in a `Str`, but callee-side arrives an `Int`

Comment: @Christoph I dropped the "also". I hope it's accurate now.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are understanding it backwards.  The signature `Int(Cool)` *accepts* a `Cool` (the more general type) and promotes to to an `Int` locally, not the other way around.  So you can give it a `Str` and it will convert that to an `Int`, which does *not* happen if you specify `Int` in the signature.  You keep talking about inconveniencing the caller -- what inconvenience is the caller experiencing by not being forced to do the coercion himself?

Comment: The inconvenience is that if I have a type that is not `Cool` but can coerce to `Int` I either have to make it `Cool` or perform the conversion on the caller side.

Comment: If it coerces to `Int` then it coerces to `Cool`, because `Int` is a `Cool`.

Comment: Or is your question why one might prefer `Int(Cool)` over `Int(Any)`?  If that's the case, that would be the question to ask.

Comment: @darch That is exactly my question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** Having reviewed this answer today I've concluded I had completely misunderstood what @musiKk was getting at. This was revealed most clearly in [@darch's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874779/what-is-the-point-of-coercions-like-intcool/34890605#comment57607468_34874779) and @musiKk's response:

> @darch: Or is your question why one might prefer Int(Cool) over Int(Any)? If that's the case, that would be the question to ask.
>
> @musiKk: That is exactly my question. :)

Reviewing the many other answers I see none have addressed it the way I now think it warrants addressing.

I might be wrong of course so what I've decided to do is leave the original question as is, in particular leaving the title as is, and leave this answer as it was, and instead write a new answer addressing @darch's reformulation.

## Specify parameter type, with no coercion: `Int $x`

We could declare:

```
sub double (Int $x) { ... } # Accept only Int. (No coercion.)
```

Then this would work:

```
double(42);
```

But unfortunately typing `42` in response to this:

```
double(prompt('')); # `prompt` returns the string the user types
```

causes the `double` call to fail with `Type check failed in binding $x; expected Int but got Str ("42")` because `42`, while looking like a number, is technically a string of type `Str`, and we've asked for no coercion.

## Specify parameter type, with blanket coercion: `Int() $x`

We can introduce blanket coercion of Any value in the sub's signature:

```
sub double (Int(Any) $x) { ... } # Take Any value. Coerce to an Int.
```

Or:

```
sub double (Int() $x)    { ... } # Same -- `Int()` coerces from Any.
```

Now, if you type `42` when prompted by the `double(prompt(''));` statement, the run-time type-check failure no longer applies and instead the run-time attempts to coerce the string to an Int. If the user types a well-formed number the code just works. If they type `123abc` the coercion will fail at run-time with a nice error message:

```
Cannot convert string to number: trailing characters after number in '123⏏abc'
```

One problem with blanket coercion of Any value is that code like this:

```
class City { ... } # City has no Int coercion
my City $city;
double($city);
```

fails at run-time with the message: "Method 'Int' not found for invocant of class 'City'".

## Specify parameter type, with coercion from Cool values: `Int(Cool) $x`

We can choose a point of balance between no coercion and blanket coercion of Any value.

The best class to coerce from is often the `Cool` class, because Cool values are guaranteed to either coerce nicely to other basic types or generate a nice error message:

```
# Accept argument of type Cool or a subclass and coerce to Int:
sub double (Int(Cool) $x) { ... }
```

With this definition, the following:

```
double(42);
double(prompt(''));
```

works as nicely as it can, and:

```
double($city);
```

fails with "Type check failed in binding $x; expected Cool but got City (City)" which is arguably a little better diagnostically for the programmer than "Method 'Int' not found for invocant of class 'City'".

---

> why would foo care that the to-be-coerced type is a Foo in the first place?

Hopefully it's now obvious that the only reason it's worth limiting the coerce-from-type to `Foo` is because that's a type expected to successfully coerce to a `Bar` value (or, perhaps, fail with a friendly message).

> Could someone shed some light on this? Links to appropriate documentation and parts of the spec are appreciated as well. I couldn't find anything useful there.

The document you originally quoted is pretty much all there is for enduser doc. Hopefully it makes sense now and you're all set. If not please comment and we'll go from there.

Comment: I guess I understand now. It's still a bit arbitrary to me but I'll probably just have to get more experienced. So wouldn't it be useful to throw a compilation error (warning?) if you try to compile `X(Y)` where `Y` is not a sub type of `X`? And do you know of other useful examples besides `Int(Cool)`?

Comment: "do you know of other useful examples besides Int(Cool)?" I don't recall seeing any instantly compelling use-cases. Here's a minor abstract example. Imagine that the `City` type I invented in my answer *can* coerce to a number but you want to know if that coercion ever gets used by `double`. You can write a matching routine signature with `Int(City)` (and then log its use within the body of that version of `double`) without slowing down any code that calls `double` with an argument that isn't a `City` type.

Comment: A pair of examples from Rakudo's source code. First, [`Grammar.parsefile`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/87b10aa1ba5c6a4583dcbd25035d269732320b1a/src/core/Grammar.pm#L14) coerces to a Str but only if the value is Cool (or a sub-type, including Str itself). So a `$grammar.parsefile($val-that-isn't-Cool)` call will fail to compile. Second, [the `BUILD` submethod of StrDistance](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/0132b654104259b26a2920fb9a89f545281bb9b3/src/core/StrDistance.pm#L6). A `$value.StrDistance` call will compile provided `$value`'s of type is `Any` (or a sub-class of `Any`).

Comment: double(+prompt(''));        the + coerces the input into a Rat

Comment: @cliveholloway `+` coerces its argument to a number; if the number is "literally a Rat" -- a string that corresponds to a Rat literal -- then the result is a Rat, but not otherwise. Rat literals include both `3/4` and `0.75` (which are basically the same value in Perl 6). Using `+` is a nice simple explicit call-site numeric coercer that serves as an alternative to the explicit signature-site coercion this SO question/answer is about but it uses the same plumbing. (Btw, I reread my answer to try understand your comment and realized I'd made mistakes, so I've also rewritten my answer.)

Answer (score 5):

What this does is accept a value that is a subtype of *Cool*, and tries to transform it into an *Int*. At that point it **is** an *Int* no matter what it was before.

So

```
sub double ( Int(Cool) $n ) { $n * 2 }
```

can really be thought of as ( I think this is how it was actually implemented in Rakudo )

```
# Int is a subtype of Cool otherwise it would be Any or Mu
proto sub double ( Cool $n ) {*}

# this has the interior parts that you write
multi sub double (  Int $n ) { $n * 2 }

# this is what the compiler writes for you
multi sub double ( Cool $n ) {
    # calls the other multi since it is now an Int
    samewith Int($n);
}
```

So this accepts any of *Int*, *Str*, *Rat*, *FatRat*, *Num*, *Array*, *Hash*, etc. and tries to convert it into an *Int* before calling `&infix:<*>` with it, and `2`.

```
say double '  5  '; # 25
say double 2.5;     # 4
say double [0,0,0]; # 6
say double { a => 0, b => 0 }; # 4
```

You might restrict it to a *Cool* instead of *Any* as all *Cool* values are essentially required to provide a coercion to *Int*.

( `:( Int(Any) $ )` can be shortened to just `:( Int() $ )` )

---

The reason you might do this is that you need it to be an `Int` inside the sub because you are calling other code that does different things with different types.

```
sub example ( Int(Cool) $n ) returns Int {
    other-multi( $n ) * $n;
}

multi sub other-multi ( Int $ ) { 10 }
multi sub other-multi ( Any $ ) {  1 }

say example 5;   # 50
say example 4.5; # 40
```

In this particular case you could have written it as one of these

```
sub example ( Cool $n ) returns Int {
    other-multi( Int($n) ) * Int($n);
}

sub example ( Cool $n ) returns Int {
    my $temp = Int($n);
    other-multi( $temp ) * $temp;
}

sub example ( Cool $n is copy ) returns Int {
    $n = Int($n);
    other-multi( $n ) * $n;
}
```

None of them are as clear as the one that uses the signature to coerce it for you.

---

Normally for such a simple function you can use one of these and it will probably do what you want.

```
my &double = * * 2; # WhateverCode
my &double = * × 2; # ditto

my &double = { $_ * 2 };       # bare block
my &double = { $^n * 2 };      # block with positional placeholder
my &double = -> $n { $n * 2 }; # pointy block

my &double = sub ( $n ) { $n * 2 } # anon sub
my &double = anon sub double ( $n ) { $n * 2 } # anon sub with name

my &double = &infix:<*>.assuming(*,2); # curried
my &double = &infix:<*>.assuming(2);

sub double ( $n ) { $n * 2 } # same as :( Any $n )
```

Comment: I know *what* it does. I want to know *why* one would need it. You have one sentence with "reason" in it and I just don't get it. Why would I "essentially" require the type to provide a coercion to `Int` when `Int()` by itself already specifies that requirement unambiguously? (Also not familiar with `proto` and information about it is very hard to come by. Seems to be about prototypes...)

Comment: @musiKk When you call a multi sub you are actually calling a proto sub that then calls the appropriate multi candidate.

Comment: Again, you are super helpful in answering the "what". I want to know "why" you would potentially inconvenience the caller. In `Socket::INET` one methods want a `Cool`, another an `Int(Cool)`. Both times it's semantically the number of bytes. It's probably out of scope for this question; I just want to understand the reasons so I know what to do when designing APIs myself.

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something?  I'm not a Perl 6 expert, but it appears the syntax allows one to specify independently both **what input types are permissible** and **how the input will be presented to the function**.

Restricting the allowable input is useful because it means the code will result in an error, rather than a silent (useless) type conversion when the function is called with a nonsensical parameter.

I don't think an example where the two types are not in a hierarchical relationship makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Per [comments on the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874779/what-is-the-point-of-coercions-like-intcool/34890605#comment57607468_34874779), a better version of @musiKk's question "What is the point of coercions like Int(Cool)?" turned out to be:

> Why might one prefer `Int(Cool)` over `Int(Any)`?

A corollary, which I'll also address in this answer, is:

> Why might one prefer `Int(Any)` over `Int(Cool)`?

First, a list of various related options:

```
sub _Int_strong (Int       $) {} # Argument must be Int
sub _Int_cool   (Int(Cool) $) {} # Argument must be Cool; Int invoked
sub _Int_weak   (Int(Any)  $) {} # Argument must be Any;  Int invoked
sub _Int_weak2  (Int()     $) {} # same
sub _Any        (Any       $) {} # Argument must be Any
sub _Any2       (          $) {} # same
sub _Mu         (Mu        $) {} # Weakest typing - just memory safe (Mu)

_Int_strong val; # Fails to bind if val is not an Int
_Int_cool   val; # Fails to bind if val is not Cool. Int invoked.
_Int_weak   val; # Fails to bind if val is not Any.  Int invoked.
_Any        val; # Fails to bind if val is Mu
_Mu         val; # Will always bind. If val is a native value, boxes it.
```

## Why might one prefer `Int(Cool)` over `Int(Any)`?

Because `Int(Cool)` is slightly stronger typing. The argument must be of type `Cool` rather than the broader `Any` and:

- Static analysis will reject binding code written to pass an argument that isn't `Cool` to a routine whose corresponding parameter has the type constraint `Int(Cool)`. If static analysis shows there is no other routine candidate able to accept the call then the compiler will reject it at compile time. This is one of the meanings of "strong typing" explained in the last section of this answer.
- If a value *is* `Cool` then it is guaranteed to have a well behaved `.Int` conversion method. So it will not yield a `Method not found` error at run-time and can be relied on to provide a good error message if it fails to produce a converted to integer value.

## Why might one prefer `Int(Any)` over `Int(Cool)`?

Because `Int(Any)` is slightly weaker typing in that the argument can be of any regular type and P6 will just try and make it work:

- `.Int` will be called on an argument that's passed to a routine whose corresponding parameter has the type constraint `Int(...)` no matter what the `...` is. Provided the passed argument has an `.Int` method the call and subsequent conversion has a chance of succeeding.
- If the `.Int` fails then the error message will be whatever the `.Int` method produces. If the argument is actually `Cool` then the `.Int` method will produce a good error message if it fails to convert to an `Int`. Otherwise the `.Int` method is presumably not a built in one and the result will be pot luck.

## Why `Foo(Bar)` in the first place?

And what's all this about weak and strong typing?

An `Int(...)` constraint on a function parameter is going to result in either:

- A failure to type check; or
- An`.Int` conversion of the corresponding argument that forces it to its integer value -- or fails, leaving the corresponding parameter containing a `Failure`.

Using Wikipedia definitions as they were at the time of writing this answer (2019) this type checking and attempted conversion will be:

- [strong typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing#Definitions_of_%22strong%22_or_%22weak%22) in the sense that a type constraint like `Int(...)` is "use of programming language types in order to both capture invariants of the code, and ensure its correctness, and definitely exclude certain classes of programming errors";
- Currently *weak typing* in Rakudo in the sense that Rakudo does not check the `...` in `Int(...)` at compile time even though in theory it could. That is, `sub double (Int $x) {}; double Date;` yields a *compile time* error (`Calling double(Date) will never work`) whereas `sub double (Int(Cool) $x) {}; double Date;` yields a *run time* error (`Type check failed in binding`).
- [type conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion);
- [weak typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) in the sense that it's [*implicit* type conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) in the sense that the compiler will handle the `.Int` coercion as part of carrying out the call;
- [*explicit* type conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Explicit_type_conversion) in the sense that the `Int(...)` constraint is explicitly directing the compiler to do the conversion as part of binding a call;
- *checked* explicit type conversion -- P6 only does type safe conversions/coercions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is as simple as you may not want to restrict the argument to `Int` even though you will be treating it as `Int` within the sub. say for some reason you want to be able to multiply an Array by a Hash, but fail if the args can't be treated as `Int` (i.e. is not `Cool`).

```
my @a = 1,2,3;
my %h = 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2;
say @a.Int; # 3 (List types coerced to the equivalent of .elems when treated as Int)
say %h.Int; # 2

sub m1(Int $x, Int $y) {return $x * $y}
say m1(3,2); # 6
say m1(@a,%h); # does not match

sub m2(Int(Cool) $x, Int(Cool) $y) {return $x * $y}
say m2('3',2); # 6
say m2(@a,%h); # 6
say m2('foo',2); # does not match
```

of course, you could also do this without the signature because the math operation will coerce the type automatically:

```
sub m3($x,$y) {return $x * $y}
say m3(@a,%h); # 6
```

however, this defers your type check to the inside of the sub, which kind of defeats the purpose of a signature and prevents you from making the sub a `multi`

Answer (score 1):

All subtypes of `Cool` will be (as Cool requires them to) coerced to an `Int`.  So if an operator or routine internal to your sub only works with `Int` arguments, you don't have to add an extra statement/expression converting to an Int nor does that operator/routine's code need to account for other subtypes of `Cool`.  It enforces that the argument will be an `Int` inside of your sub wherever you use it.

Your example is backwards:

```
class Foo { method foomethod { say 'foomethod' } }
class Bar {}

class Quux is Bar {
  method Foo { Foo.new }
}

sub foo(Foo(Bar) $c) {
#= converts $c of type Bar to type Foo
#= returns result of foomethod
  say $c.WHAT;    #-> (Foo)
  $c.foomethod    #-> foomethod
}

foo(Quux.new)
```